# why wait boost::asio::read_until after hour/days

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Try to program for `boost::asio` server socket. That program working properly. But continuedly run after some hours (or) days `read_until` function to next line not move. This problem find out, i put and check the log. So want to any solution for this problem or why occur this problem.

that server code  : -

```
void server::server_fn()
{
    log(_INFO_, "Test: Start server component");
    boost::system::error_code error; 
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;

    log(_INFO_,"Test: Before read_until");
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, buf, "\n");
    log(_INFO_,"Test: After read_until");

    string read_name = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());

    log(_INFO_, "Test: Before write");
    write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("Accepted"), error);
    log(_INFO_, "Test: After write");

    if (error)
        log(_ERROR_, "Failed to write");

}
```

This program run to stop in log  **log(*INFO*,"Test: Before read_until")** that line not move not line. This problem occur after hour or days.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation of `read_until` explains

> The read_until function is a composed operation that reads data into a dynamic buffer sequence, or into a streambuf, until it contains a delimiter, matches a regular expression, or a function object indicates a match.

The [specific overload](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until/overload11.html) documents:

> This function is used to read data into the specified streambuf until
> the streambuf's get area contains the specified delimiter. The call
> will block until one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The get area of the streambuf contains the specified delimiter.
> - An error occurred.

So there's your answer:

> Q. why wait boost::asio::read_until after hour/days

A. Because the peer (remote end) does not send `"\n"` and no error occurs.

### Timeouts

If you need to limit the potential time, use async operations. They can be canceled, e.g. with an `asio::deadline_timer`.